# using RStudio as an pseudo shiny app

Tags: r, user-interface, shiny, rstudio

This is a rather general, and curious question.

I am working on a moderately complex shiny app, using custom HTML and Javascript code (with menus and independent dialogs), using shiny as a communication protocol with the base R. Everything looks very nice, until I realised that RStudio itself is a web page (or am I wrong?)

The main reason to design a GUI in a shiny app is it's cross-platform, but it still needs to be opened in a web browser. Conversely, RStudio is also a web page but opens just like any other installed software. To me, it looks like a self-contained web browser with different menus.

Now the question: is it possible to use parts of RStudio in a different "app"?
For example, I would love to separate the code editor and the console from RStudio and use them in conjunction with other HTML and Javascript code to produce a GUI similar to RStudio but with different purposes.

To better explain why: RStudio is fantastic, but it has the one big disadvantage (no flame intended, others think this is a feature) that everything must fit in the same page. In order to make the code editor larger, one needs to shrink other parts of the interface. I would like to make them separate dialogs, creating divs when a menu is selected.

Thanks in advance,
Adrian

Comment: Maybe irrelevant, but we can [pop out the editor window](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/207126217-Using-Source-Windows) to make it larger.

Comment: Awesome... a very good step in the direction of a flexible UI. The other panes are still fighting for the same space, but this is already much better.

The question is still interesting, though: could one "extract" some parts (modules) from RStudio and build something else on top?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

engineer from RStudio here. You are correct about RStudio itself being "a web page"; the whole UI is effectively done in HTML. There's even a version of RStudio which already runs in a web browser called RStudio Server.

There are unfortunately no extensibility points to do what you want. RStudio internals are largely anonymized and insulated from external access, which make them difficult to separate, re-use, or connect to other services. Here are a few pointers that may be helpful, however:

- As a commenter pointed out, it is now possible to pop out the editor window.
- You can make an [RStudio Add-in](https://rstudio.github.io/rstudioaddins/) which runs in a separate browser window when invoked. Depending on what you want to do in your separate window, you may be able to accomplish it with an add-in.

If you can't use add-ins, the easiest thing to do is actually to just change RStudio itself. It's an [open source project](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio), so you're welcome to hack on it and make improvements in reusability or UI flexibility. We welcome pull requests. :-)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Jonathan. It's what I had expected, to end up hacking RStudio to get what I want... and one day I will probably (try to) do that. My aim is something similar to the QCAGUI package in R, but opened as RStudio does (similar to an installed program), not as a shiny app which opens in a web browser.